# Is there a way to get values of stocks to Java faster?

Tags: java, stock

I made a simple java program that lets you create a stocks scanner/screener. There aren't many features yet, but there is a problem with existing features. I have a class that has a method that creates an array of all stock tickers and returns it. Here it is:

```
package classes;

import Utility.ArrayModification;
import variables.Ticker;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Market {
    public static Ticker[] getAllTickers() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Ticker[] allTickers = {};
        File currentDirectory = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
        String allTickersDirectory = currentDirectory + "\\src\\AllTickers.txt";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(allTickersDirectory));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(!(line.contains("^"))) {
                allTickers = ArrayModification.appendTicker(allTickers, new Ticker(line));
            }
        }
        return allTickers;
    }
}
```

AllTickers.txt is a text file with the names of all tickers in it. I also have another class that stores a datatype, Ticker. Here it is:

```
package variables;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Ticker {
    private String savedSymbol;
    public Ticker(String symbol) {
        savedSymbol = symbol;
    }
    public String getTicker() {
        return savedSymbol;
    }
    public Ticker setTicker(String symbol) {
        savedSymbol = symbol;
        return this;
    }
    public double getPrice() throws IOException {
        try {
            String stringURL = "https://markets.businessinsider.com/stocks/" + savedSymbol + "-stock";
            URL url = new URL(stringURL);
            URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);
            String stringPrice = "-1";
            String line = buff.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.contains("price: ")) {
                    int target = line.indexOf("price: ");
                    int deci = line.indexOf(".", target);
                    int start = deci;
                    int stop = deci;
                    while (line.charAt(start) != ' ') {
                        start--;
                    }
                    while (line.charAt(stop) != ',') {
                        stop++;
                    }
                    stringPrice = line.substring(start + 1, stop);
                    break;
                }
                line = buff.readLine();
            }
            double price = Double.parseDouble(stringPrice);
            return price;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public double getMarketCap() throws IOException {
        try {
            String stringURL = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + savedSymbol;
            URL url = new URL(stringURL);
            URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);
            String stringMarketCap = "-1";
            double finalMarketCap = -1;
            String line = buff.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.contains(">Market Cap<")) {
                    int deci = line.indexOf(".");
                    int start = deci;
                    int stop = deci;
                    while (line.charAt(start) != '>') {
                        start--;
                    }
                    while (line.charAt(stop) != '<') {
                        stop++;
                    }
                    stringMarketCap = line.substring(start + 1, stop - 1);
                    double marketCap = Double.parseDouble(stringMarketCap);
                    if (line.charAt(stop - 1) == 'B') {
                        finalMarketCap = marketCap * 1000000000;
                    } else if (line.charAt(stop - 1) == 'M') {
                        finalMarketCap = marketCap * 1000000;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                line = buff.readLine();
            }
            return finalMarketCap;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Using all of these, you can create a simple scanner that scans for stocks with a price of, for example, 0 - 15. You can do this by doing this:

```
import classes.Market; 
import variables.Ticker;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Ticker[] allTickers = Market.getAllTickers();
        for(int i = 0; i< allTickers.length; i++){
            Ticker ticker = allTickers[i];
            if(ticker.getPrice() > 0 && ticker.getPrice() < 15) {
                System.out.println(ticker.getTicker());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out all of the qualifying stocks. However, it is EXTREMELY slow. So slow that it's basically unusable. It is this way because the ticker.getPrice() method has to connect to markets.businessinsider.com, extract the HTML code, find the correct index, and get the price for every single stock out of the 6000 in AllTIckers.txt. Would there be a way to do this faster?

Comment: Get a faster internet connection?  Seriously you should be looking a multi-threading for this.

Comment: You should definitely NOT be scraping web pages.  There are many stock price APIs (some even are free) and you should be using one of those instead.

Comment: @JimGarrison What are some free ones as I couldn't find a good free one?